# Como criar um loop dentro do corpo do e-mail no outlook usando VBA

Tags: vba, loop, excel-vba, envio-de-email, outlook

Durante o dia envio alguns e-mails que contém uma mensagem padrão e algumas variáveis (*ativo*, *quatidade* e *preço*). Preciso colocar um loop de dados dentro do corpo do e-mail usando o excel a partir da variável *ativo*. Tentei de algumas formas, mas ele acabou criando um novo e-mail para cada linha da planilha. Segue o código:

```
Sub modelo_auditoria()

Set objeto_outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For linha = 2 To 5

Set Email = objeto_outlook.createitem(0)

Email.display

Email.To = Cells(2, 7).Value
Email.Subject = Cells(8, 7).Value

Email.body = Cells(6, 7).Value & "," & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
& "Conforme conversado, gostaria de realizar as ordens abaixo na sua conta " & Cells(4, 7).Value & ":" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
& "Ativo: " & Cells(2, 2) & Chr(10) _
& "Quantidade: " & Chr(10) _
& "Preço: " & Chr(10) _
& "Qualquer dúvida estou à disposição." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
& "Att,,"

Next


End Sub
```

[image: Tabela usada no código]

Agradeço muito desde já! Abs

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Sub modelo_auditoria()

Set objeto_outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Email = objeto_outlook.createitem(0)

Email.To = Cells(2, 7).Value
Email.cc = Cells(linha, 8).Value
Email.Subject = Cells(8, 7).Value
vtexto = Cells(6, 7).Value & "," & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
         "Conforme conversado, gostaria de realizar as ordens abaixo na sua conta xp " & Cells(4, 7).Value & ":" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _

For linha = 2 To 4
    vtexto2 = vtexto2 & _
    "Ativo: " & Cells(linha, 2) & Chr(10) & _
    "Quantidade: " & Cells(linha, 4) & Chr(10) & _
    "Preço: " & Cells(linha, 5) & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
Next

vtexto = vtexto & vtexto2 & "Qualquer dúvida estou à disposição." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Att,,"

Email.body = vtexto
Email.display   'se quiser enviar direto e so trocar por display por send

End Sub
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).